# Matching Data using Spark Java RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

IN my recent BigData project I need to work on Spark.

The first requirement is as below

We have two  sets of data coming from different data-sources  lets say one from flatFile and other from HDFS.

datasets may or may not have common columns but we have the mapping rules in hand for e.g.

function1(data1.columnA)==function2(data2.columnB)

I tried to achive this by executing foreach on rdd one inside other  but this is not allowed in Spark,

org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$sc(RDD.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:910)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:332)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
        at com.pramod.engine.DataMatchingEngine.lambda$execute$4e658232$1(DataMatchingEngine.java:44)
        at com.pramod.engine.DataMatchingEngine$$Lambda$9/1172080526.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:332)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:332)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)

Please help me with best possible way to achieve this.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details (at least I didn't understand) and exactly... what do you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two RDDs, lets call them `A` and `B`, which need to be joined however the ID needs some mangling before you can do so. Assuming this is correct then...

```
// The data to be processed. How you load it and 
// what it looks like is not important.
case class Item (id : Int)

val A = sc.parallelize(Seq(Item(1), Item(2)))
val B = sc.parallelize(Seq(Item(10), Item(20)))

// We then map it to `key, value`, to keep things simple 
// A.id should be id * 100 and B.id should be id * 10
val aWithKey = A.map(x => (x.id * 100, x))
val bWithKey = B.map(x => (x.id * 10, x))

// We can now join the two data sets.
aWithKey.join(bWithKey).collect
```